# Is it possible to pre-configure apps like OneDrive, DropBox using MDM or Apple Configurator?

Tags: ios, dropbox, onedrive, mdm, apple-configurator

I am using MDM to configure Email accounts on the devices using 
Mail/Exchange ActiveSync payload. 
I was wondering if there is a way where I can also configure OneDrive and DropBox accounts using MDM or Apple Configurator.
I know we can install the Apps but is there a way where I can add a specific account too?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Perhaps this is better suited for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: iOS MDM ([documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW68)) does have a way to configure applications over the air but the apps have to support it. Some MDM vendors have this functionality.

Comment: @cteski Thanks for the info!! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application has different capabilities for being provisioned as it's being sent down to the device, therefore, there's no easy answer to this

However, firstly, I'd start with https://appconfig.org which is an initiative to getting developers to use the same format for Managed App Config. This also allows MDM vendors to "read" the Managed app config capabilities of an app, saving you the hassle of having to look this information up on the web

You'll struggle with Microsoft apps beyond VERY basic capabilities. However, for DropBox, there's some information here: [Dropbox EMM support](https://blogs.dropbox.com/business/2016/05/emm-now-available-through-ibm-and-other-providers/)